# Error Incorporating Apple's ClassKit and swift classes into existing app with Objective-C++ and C++ classes in .mm files

Tags: c++, ios, swift, objective-c++

I'm doing a test project to see if Apple's ClassKit for schools can be incorporated into an existing ios education app with Objective-C++ and C++ classes in .mm files and am getting an error in the ...-Swift.h bridging header (automatically created by xcode when I add a swift file), even before importing the bridging header into the ObjectiveC++ files to allow them to access the Swift classes.

As a simple test project, ObjectiveC-Test, I created a class:

//  Quiz.swift

```
import Foundation 
import ClassKit 

@objcMembers public class Quiz : NSObject
{
    var mTitle            : String
    var mNumberOfProblems : Double
    var mNumberCorrect    : Double

    var context = CLSContext (type : CLSContextType.quiz, identifier : "Test", title : "Parent Test")

    override init ()
    {
        self.mTitle            = ""
        self.mNumberOfProblems = 0
        self.mNumberCorrect    = 0

        super.init()
    }


    init (title : String)
    {
        self.mTitle            = title
        self.mNumberOfProblems = 0
        self.mNumberCorrect    = 0
    }

}  // end class


protocol Node
{
    var parent      : Node?          { get }
    var children    : [Node]?        { get }
    var identifier  : String         { get }
    var contextType : CLSContextType { get }
}


extension Quiz : Node
{
    var parent      : Node?          { return nil }
    var children    : [Node]?        { return nil }
    var identifier  : String         { return mTitle }
    var contextType : CLSContextType { return .quiz }
}
```

"protocol Node" and "extension Quiz : Node" are taken from the Apple GreatPlays project which illustrates how to incorporate ClassKit into projects but is strictly Swift code.
CLSContext is a ClassKit class and doesn't cause any problems, but "CLSContextType", an Enumeration in ClassKit causes and error in the ...-Swift.h header: "Unknown Type Name 'CLSContextType'.

However, in the quiz class, "CLSContextType.quiz" in "var context = CLSContext (...)"
doesn't cause any problem.
But if I add the line" "var contextType = CLSContextType.quiz" to the quiz class I get the error.

The relevant code in the xcode-generated swift bridging header (ObjectiveC_Test-Swift.h) is:

```
@class CLSContext;

SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC15ObjectiveC_Test4Quiz")
@interface Quiz : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * _Nonnull mTitle;
@property (nonatomic) double mNumberOfProblems;
@property (nonatomic) double mNumberCorrect;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLSContext * _Nonnull context;
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString * _Nonnull)title OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end


@interface Quiz (SWIFT_EXTENSION(ObjectiveC_Test))
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString * _Nonnull identifier;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLSContextType contextType;
@end
```

The error occurs in the next to last line: "CLSContextType contextType":
"Unknown type name 'CLSContextType'".
It also generates an error: "Interface type cannot be statically allocated" but I think that's due to the first error.
"CLSContext" in the eighth line doesn't cause any error.

If I comment out the CLSContextType lines in the protocol and in the node extension the project runs fine.

The project is under xcode 10.0 and ios 11.4.

Build settings include:

```
Packaging
   Defines Module:    Yes

Build Options
   Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries:  Yes

Swift Compiler - General:
   Install Objective-C Compatibility Header:  Yes
   Objective-C Bridging Header:   ObjectiveC-Test/ObjectiveC-Test-Bridging-Header.h
   Objective-C-Generated Interface Header Name:   ObjectiveC_Test-Swift.h

Apple Clang - Language - C++
   C++ Language Dialect:  GNU++14 [std=gnu++14]
   C++ Standard Library:  libcc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

Removing "@objcMembers" from the Quiz class eliminated the CLSContextType error in the xcode-created bridging header, but then the class properties were no longer accessible from the Objective-C++ .mm files.
Adding "@obj" to those fixed that but didn't work with contextType.

The class properties could then be accessed and printed in the Objective-C++ .mm file.

The protocol properties, including the CLSContextType, could be printed in the Objective-C++ .mm file from a swift function (start) and node extension function (printContextTypeFromNodeExtension).

```
//  @objcMembers public class Quiz : NSObject
public class Quiz : NSObject
{
    @objc var mTitle            : String
    @objc var mNumberOfProblems : Double
    @objc var mNumberCorrect    : Double
//    @objc var mLessonContextType : CLSContextType { return .lesson }  //  doesn't work
                                                           //  causes same bridging error


@objc func start ()
{
    print ("printing title from start() in swift: \(mTitle)")
    print ("printing identifier from start() in swift: \(identifier)")

    print ("printing CLSContextType from start() in swift: \(contextType.rawValue)")
    printContextTypeFromNodeExtension ()
}

}  // end class

extension Node
{
    func printContextTypeFromNodeExtension ()
    {
        print ("printing CLSContextType from Node extension: \(contextType.rawValue)")
    }    
}
```

Objective-C++ .mm file:

```
Quiz * Q1 = [ [Quiz alloc] init];
Q1.mTitle = @"Place Value Blocks";
Q1.mNumberOfProblems = 10;
Q1.mNumberCorrect    = 3;

printf ("printing mTitle from objc: %s \n", [Q1.mTitle UTF8String] );
printf ("printing mNumberCorrect from objc: %f \n", Q1.mNumberCorrect);

[Q1 start];

Results:

printing mTitle from objc: Place Value Blocks 
printing mNumberCorrect from objc: 3.000000 

printing title from start() in swift: Place Value Blocks
printing identifier from start() in swift: Place Value Blocks
printing CLSContextType from start() in swift: 8
printing CLSContextType from Node extension: 8
```

Adding "@objc" to the Node protocol allowed all the Node properties to be accessed in the Objective-C++ .mm files except the  the CLSContextType.
If that's left in, the swift bridging header error returns.

```
@objc protocol Node
{
    var parent      : Node?          { get }
    var children    : [Node]?        { get }
    var identifier  : String         { get }
    //  var contextType : CLSContextType { get }  // error if included when "@objc" added
}


extension Quiz : Node
{
    var parent      : Node?          { return nil }
    var children    : [Node]?        { return nil }
    var identifier  : String         { return mTitle }
//    var contextType : CLSContextType { return .quiz }
}

Objective-C++ .mm file:

printf ("printing parent from objc: %p \n", [Q1 parent] );
printf ("printing children from objc: %p \n", [Q1 children] );
printf ("printing identifier from objc: %s \n", [Q1.identifier UTF8String] );

Results:

printing parent from objc: 0x0 
printing children from objc: 0x0 
printing identifier from objc: Place Value Blocks
```

Conclusion: I found a comment in another post that said that Enumerations and Structures defined in Swift aren't available in Objective-C, but couldn't find the reference, so it may be preferable to use classes instead of structures and deal with Enumerations only in swift files.

Answer (score 0):

Does your ObjC header import ClassKit?

The protocol, it needs to be declared with @objc.

```
@objc protocol Node
```

Comment: If you meant importing ClassKit to the xcode generated bridging header, adding "
#include <ClassKit/ClassKit.h>" to ObjectiveC_Test-swift.h didn't work, although I'm not sure I can change that bridging header since it's xcode generated.

Comment: A few things, is the ClassKit framework imported by your project? With ObjC having #import is not enough.
The other thing, the extension too needs to be declared with @objc.

Comment: ClassKit is imported into the project.  @objc to the extension still causes the error.